# CSS box width not changing

Tags: javascript, css, interact.js

I'm following this library for drag and drop on mobile:

http://interactjs.io/

Specifically the second paragraph: "Drag and drop"

I am trying to change the size of the blue boxes with class drag-drop by editing:

```
.drag-drop {
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
padding: 2em 0.5em;

color: #fff;
background-color: #29e;
border: solid 2px #fff;

-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
      transform: translate(0px, 0px);

transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

However this does not seem to do the trick. What am I missing? CSS is my weak point so consider me as a basic user.

Comment: Scroll down to Resizing in the interactjs examples.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo, it's WIDTH not WEIGHT

width: 10px;